# how to play Wav file

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, wav

Below is my code 
i unable to play SnareHitSample.wav file.
i don't know where i am getting wrong.

```
-(void)playAudioFiles
{
    NSString * path;
    AVAudioPlayer * snd;
    NSError * err;
    NSString *name;
    name = @"SnareHitSample.wav";
    path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        snd = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                      error:&err] ;
        if (! snd) {
            NSLog(@"Sound named '%@' had error %@", name, [err localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [snd prepareToPlay];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sound file '%@' doesn't exist at '%@'", name, path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank everyone i declared avaudioplayer object in .h files my issue get solved.

```
  {
 AVAudioPlayer *player1;
  }
```

Comment: When audioPlayer/theAudio gets out of scope it gets deallocated and then sound playing will be stopped. Add a property to the class like you did and it will remain for the duration of the object life-time.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"SnareHitSample"
                                     ofType:@"wav"]];
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:url
               error:&error];
if (error)
{
  NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else
{
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
    [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:INT32_MAX]; // for continuous play
}
```

Comment: you need to copy(drag and drop) that SnareHitSample.wav into  your project. Did u add that??? @MohammedEbrahim

Comment: it their i try it mp3 file also but same problem

Comment: Go to build Phases  and check if SnareHitSample.wav  is in your copy bundle.  if not add it and then try.

Comment: have you added <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> in your .h file?

Comment: @MohammedEbrahim i feel your function playAudioFiles is not being called. Add break point and check!

Comment: When audioPlayer gets out of scope it gets deallocated and then sound playing will be stopped. Add a property to the class and it will remain for the duration of the object life-time.

Answer (score 1):

try Below Code:

```
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                                                      pathForResource:@"SnareHitSample" ofType:@"wav"]] error:NULL];
       [theAudio play];
```

and you will get rid of this.. any query revert me..

Comment: Have you added .wav file or not in project?

Comment: and have you added audiotoolbox framework and avfoundation framework also.  and imported #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
  ?

Comment: When theAudio gets out of scope it gets deallocated and then sound playing will be stopped. Add a property to the class and it will remain for the duration of the object life-time.